# Consecutive Blank space Removal in C

Tags: c, whitespace

A text file contains a bunch of characters. There are no tab characters within the file. Write a program that replaces two or more consecutive blanks by a single blank. The input from this program should come from a file whose name has been supplied via argv[1]. The output from this program should go to standard output.

Input:

```
Let’s   go  to  the movies.
```

Output:

```
Let’s go to the movies.
```

This is what i have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char line;
    FILE* fin;
    int i=0;

    fin=fopen("textfile38", "r");
    fscanf(fin,"%c",&line);
    while((i<=line || line ==' '));
    {
        if(line !=' ')
        {
           putchar(line);
           i=i+1;
        }
    else
    {
        putchar(' ');
    }
    while(line == ' ')
    {
        i=i+1;
    }
  }
  printf("%c \n", getchar());
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

It doesn't give me an output I'm not sure what I did wrong if anyone could help me NOT just give me the answer that would be great thank you.

Comment: Hint: have a flag to remember if the last read character was a space.

Comment: What is the purpose of this test? `i<=line`

Comment: Learn to use a debugger and step through it.

Comment: Thanks @BasileStarynkevitch I'm not sure how to put a flag in...

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta It compiles but doesnt do anything.

Comment: @bmargulies im using a terminal not a program to debug it thanks though

Comment: What debugging *have* you attempted?

Comment: I have tried rewritting the code and changing different parts of it to get it to run correctly and it just got me stuck.

Comment: @Cka91405: Try to think by yourself. We won't help you by doing *your* homework. The goal of this homework is to improve your coding skills & thoughts.

Comment: I never asked for any one to do my homework maybe you should re read the question. I specifically said i needed help NOT someone to just give me the answer. thank you though ! I have had enough help from you.

Comment: Build a mental model of what your program should be doing, how each line of code should be modifying data/variables. Then watch your program's state while it's executing (with a debugger or with a whole bunch of `printf`s), and see where it diverges from that model.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you to progress:
It seems you read only one character **before** the while loop. You might want to read characters continuously **inside** the while loop and stop looping when end of file is reached.

Second hint:
You leave the file open. What should you do before exiting your program?

Comment: Thank you for you help obviously they think I'm stupid or something!

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to be a newbie... :)

Comment: Yeah I see that which is totally unfair because they were once in my shoes (not understanding and in need of a boost/hint)