# Blank Space Removal- C Programming

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consecutive Blank space Removal in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113938/consecutive-blank-space-removal-in-c)

Prompt:
A text file contains a bunch of characters. There are no tab characters within the file. Write a program that replaces two or more consecutive blanks by a single blank. The input from this program should come from a file whose name has been supplied via argv[1]. The output from this program should go to standard output.

Question: How to remove consecutive blank spaces in a text file?

I have started my code and it compiles but then doesn't do anything. Im not sure where I went wrong with the code. I want the code to basically simulated a FMS which says that if the text read in is equal to a blank space two times in a row then place the text from the file there but I am having trouble getting it to print out correctly.

Input:

```
Let’s   go  to  the movies.
```

Output:

```
Let’s go to the movies.
```

My written Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int i;
    char c;
    FILE* fin;

    fin=fopen("textfile38", "r");
    fscanf(fin,"%c", &c);
    while((i=getchar()) !=EOF)
            putchar(c);
    if(i ==' ')
    {
            putchar(i);
    }
    else
    {
            putchar(' ');
    }
    printf("%c \n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

I get it to return L. Am I not reading in all of the characters? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char c;
    FILE* fin;

    fin=fopen("textfile38", "r");
    while(fscanf(fin,"%c", &c) !=EOF){
            if(c ==' ')
            {
                    putchar(c);
            }
            else
            {
                    putchar(' ');
            }
            printf("%c", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Only problem is that the spaces are still there from the input, also its printing vertically not horizontally, and i don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to keep state as to what you have seen, so something like....

```
   int seenspace = 0;
   while((i=getchar()) !=EOF) {
   {
       if(i != ' ')
       {
            if (seenspace) 
               putchar(' ');
            putchar(i);
            seenspace = 0;
       } else {
            if (seenspace)  {
               putchar(' '); 
               seenspace = 0; 
            } else {
               seeenspace = 1;
            }
       }
   }
   if (seenspace) // flush the training blank if any 
      putchar(' ');
```

Comment: oh that kind of looks like what i was starting in the beginning. Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

getchar() reads a character from stdin, whereas you are looking to read from a file. The fscanf that you are using works, which is why you are seeing the L, but getchar() will not return anything. Keep using fscanf().

Comment: okay thank you! I will use that I'm going to try and work with the information I have just received on my code.